# Randomize order of Python OrderedDict

Tags: python, random, ordereddictionary

`samplesDict` is a defaultdict of OrderedDict objects; from [Python collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html). For each OrderedDict, I would like to create a copy where the order is randomized.

```
import collections
import copy
import random
...
randomizedSamplesDict = copy.deepcopy(samplesDict)
for k, i in samplesDict.iteritems():
  random.shuffle(i)
```

But I keep getting a `KeyError: 56` at the `random.shuffle(i)` line; error integer (e.g. `56`) is different each time.

To illustrate, one of the OrderedDicts may be

```
OrderedDict([
  ('This is the first key', ['foo', 'baz']),
  ('And the second key', ['buz', 'baz']),
  ('Finally the third key', ['bar', 'foo'])])
```

And I would like the copy to become

```
OrderedDict([
  ('Finally the third key', ['bar', 'foo']),
  ('This is the first key', ['foo', 'baz']),
  ('And the second key', ['buz', 'baz'])])
```

Comment: The order of what is randomized? Your question doesn't make sense unless you explain what you are trying to accomplish with this.

Answer (score 2):

To randomize a OrderedDict you can do the following:

```
od = collections.OrderedDict([('This is the first key', ['foo', 'baz']), ('And the second key', ['buz', 'baz']),  ('Finally the third key', ['bar', 'foo'])])
items = od.items()
random.shuffle(items)
odrnd = collections.OrderedDict(items)
ornd
OrderedDict([('Finally the third key', ['bar', 'foo']), ('This is the first key', ['foo', 'baz']), ('And the second key', ['buz', 'baz'])])
```

Comment: I got TypeError: 'odict_items' object does not support indexing

Comment: Maybe this is because dictionaries are ordered now?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.6+ dictionaries are ordered, so solutions that worked before may create errors like `TypeError: 'odict_items' object does not support indexing`.

Instead, try:

```
items = list(my_dict.items())
random.shuffle(items)
my_dict = OrderedDict(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here; but here is one way to get your end result:

```
ordered_dicts = samplesDict.values()
```

Now, if you want to fetch the ordered dict randomly:

```
random.choice(ordered_dict)
```

If you want to fetch a value from one of the ordered dicts randomly:

```
the_dict_you_want = 1
random.choice([value for value in ordered_dicts[the_dict_you_want].values()])
```

If you just want to have random order of items from the ordered dicts, convert them to normal dicts; then shuffle the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
import copy
import random

samplesDict = collections.OrderedDict()
samplesDict[1] = 10
samplesDict[2] = 20
samplesDict[3] = 30
print samplesDict

keys = samplesDict.keys()
random.shuffle(keys)
print keys

randomizedSamplesDict = collections.OrderedDict()
for k in keys :
    randomizedSamplesDict[k] = samplesDict[k]
print randomizedSamplesDict
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)])
[2, 1, 3]
OrderedDict([(2, 20), (1, 10), (3, 30)])
```

As you can see the second dict is shuffled (by keys).

Using your data I get the output:

```
...
samplesDict = collections.OrderedDict([
  ('This is the first key', ['foo', 'baz']),
  ('And the second key', ['buz', 'baz']),
  ('Finally the third key', ['bar', 'foo'])])
...

OrderedDict([('This is the first key', ['foo', 'baz']), 
('And the second key', ['buz', 'baz']), 
('Finally the third key', ['bar', 'foo'])])

['And the second key', 'Finally the third key', 'This is the first key']

OrderedDict([('And the second key', ['buz', 'baz']), 
('Finally the third key', ['bar', 'foo']), 
('This is the first key', ['foo', 'baz'])])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are shuffling the wrong items, you should be iterating over `randomizedSamplesDict`:

```
randomizedSamplesDict = copy.deepcopy(samplesDict)
for k, i in randomizedSamplesDict.items():
  random.shuffle(i)
print(randomizedSamplesDict)
```

You have made a deepcopy of `samplesDict` so if you want to shuffle the order in `randomizedSamplesDict` you need to iterate over that dict not the original.

If you actually want a new dict with the keys and values from `samplesDict`in a random order use the items from the original dict after shuffling to create a new OrderedDict:

```
import collections
import copy
import random
samplesDict = collections.OrderedDict([
  ('This is the first key', ['foo', 'baz']),
  ('And the second key', ['buz', 'baz']),
  ('Finally the third key', ['bar', 'foo'])])

items = list(samplesDict.items())
random.shuffle(items)
randomizedSamplesDict = collections.OrderedDict(copy.deepcopy(items))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

randomizedSamplesDict = defaultdict(list)
for category, samples in samplesDict.iteritems():
  # samples is an OrderedDict object
  keys = samples.keys()
  random.shuffle(keys)
  tempOrderedDict = OrderedDict()
  for k in keys:
    tempOrderedDict[k] = samples[k]
  randomizedSamplesDict[category] = tempOrderedDict

return randomizedSamplesDict
```